# Unable to import data into MySQL table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We are having an issue importing entries into a table on MySQL version 8.0.27-0.  I have been able to reproduce the problem with a simple example.  Kindly note that all privileges have been granted to the user.

First I created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE people
(
  id  INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name  CHAR(40) NOT  NULL DEFAULT '',
  age  INT NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Then I created the file /tmp/people.txt, with the following entries:

```
1   William 25
2   Mary    37
```

There is no issue with permissions of the file because `system '/tmp/people.txt'` gives the following output:

```
mysql> system cat '/tmp/people.txt'
1   William 25
2   Mary    37
```

However, when I try

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/people.txt' INTO TABLE people;
```

I get the following error:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/people.txt' INTO TABLE people;
ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/tmp/people.txt' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
```

The file `/tmp/people.txt` has permission 777, so I am not sure what is happening.

---

When I try  `mysqlimport soverflow people.txt` from `/tmp` directory, I get the following error:

```
mysqlimport: Error: 13, Can't get stat of '/var/lib/mysql/soverflow/people.txt' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory), when using table: people
```

Comment: What is the permission on `/tmp`?

Comment: @RickJames the permission is 777.

Answer (score 1):

chmod permissions is just the beginning

## ASPECT #1 : Security

Please note the [MySQL Documentation on LOAD DATA under the heading `Security Requirements`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

> **Security Requirements**
>
> For a non-LOCAL load operation, the server reads a text file located
> on the server host, so these security requirements must be satisified:
>
> You must have the [FILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) privilege. See [Section 6.2.2, “Privileges
> Provided by MySQL”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html).
>
> The operation is subject to the [secure_file_priv](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) system variable
> setting:
>
> If the variable value is a nonempty directory name, the file must be
> located in that directory.
>
> If the variable value is empty (which is insecure), the file need only
> be readable by the server.
>
> For a LOCAL load operation, the client program reads a text file
> located on the client host. Because the file contents are sent over
> the connection by the client to the server, using LOCAL is a bit
> slower than when the server accesses the file directly. On the other
> hand, you do not need the [FILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) privilege, and the file can be located
> in any directory the client program can access.

## ASPECT #2 : File Location

Please note the error message

```
mysqlimport: Error: 13, Can't get stat of '/var/lib/mysql/soverflow/people.txt' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory), when using table: people
```

I think you might have to use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to change the location mysqld is expecting. The documentation shows this as a probable cause

> **Input File Location**
>
> These rules determine the LOAD DATA input file
> location:
>
> If LOCAL is not specified, the file must be located on the server
> host. The server reads the file directly, locating it as follows:
>
> If the file name is an absolute path name, the server uses it as
> given.
>
> If the file name is a relative path name with leading components, the
> server looks for the file relative to its data directory.
>
> If the file name has no leading components, the server looks for the
> file in the database directory of the default database.
>
> If LOCAL is specified, the file must be located on the client host.
> The client program reads the file, locating it as follows:
>
> If the file name is an absolute path name, the client program uses it
> as given.
>
> If the file name is a relative path name, the client program looks for
> the file relative to its invocation directory.
>
> When LOCAL is used, the client program reads the file and sends its
> contents to the server. The server creates a copy of the file in the
> directory where it stores temporary files. See Section B.3.3.5, “Where
> MySQL Stores Temporary Files”. Lack of sufficient space for the copy
> in this directory can cause the LOAD DATA LOCAL statement to fail.
>
> The non-LOCAL rules mean that the server reads a file named as
> ./myfile.txt relative to its data directory, whereas it reads a file
> named as myfile.txt from the database directory of the default
> database. For example, if the following LOAD DATA statement is
> executed while db1 is the default database, the server reads the file
> data.txt from the database directory for db1, even though the
> statement explicitly loads the file into a table in the db2 database:

Answer (score 0):

We were able to get mysqlimport and LOAD DATA INFILE working by changing the file user and group to **mysql**.